# Nesting IF statement inside a loop throwing error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The error I am receiving:

> Exception: The parameters (String,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var VALUE = "Hide";
  var COLUMN_NUMBER = 11;

  ui.createMenu('Hidden Rows')
      .addItem('Hide Rows w/Status = Hidden', 'menuItem1')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Unhide Rows w/Status = Hidden', 'menuItem2')
      .addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell()
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();

  for (r=1; r<lastRow; r++)  {
    ss.getRange(r,11);

      if(cellValue == VALUE){
        activeSheet.hideRow(cell);
      };
  }

}

function menuItem2() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
     .alert('Second menu item!');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var VALUE = "Hide";//global

function menuItem1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell()
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();
  for (let r=1;r<lastRow;r++)  {
    if(cellValue==VALUE){
      activeSheet.hideRow(cell.getRow());//this hides the row of the activeCell() not the row of the iteration index
    }
  }
}
```

These two values are not global scope in your script:

```
var VALUE = "Hide";
var COLUMN_NUMBER = 11;
```

They cannot get hoisted into global from function scope.

Interestingly enough that very line that caused the error does nothing.

```
ss.getRange(r,11);
```

You might have r defined to be a string some where so I declared r to have section scope in the loop.  You should probably review const,var and let in a JavaScript reference.

It's not clear to me from your script what you had it mind but perhaps this is it.

```
function runOne() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getDataRange();
  const vs=rg.getValues();
  const cell=ss.getActiveCell()
  const cellValue=cell.getValue();
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(cellValue==r[10]){
      sh.hideRows(i+1);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I pass the column number into the loop?

Comment: The column number or the row number?

Comment: Column...I am trying to loop through column 11 (column K)

Comment: No actually you're looping through rows.  And I assumed from this `ss.getRange(r,11);` that you probably wanted the cell value of column 11.  That's what my latest example does.

Comment: I didn't see that for some reason.  You are right I was looking for cell value in Column 11, but now I'm getting:  Exception: The parameters (number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.hideRow.

Comment: Please try it again.

Comment: I spent an hour reading through for/each documentation and came up with this:   ` if(r[10] == "Hide"){`   Thank you so much for your help. Based on the number of down votes I received, I'm guessing I didn't explain how I initially was troubleshooting.

Comment: Learning to use the Array looping methods is well worth your time.